# Android Studio: Cannot resolve symbol 'activity'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In Android Studio, I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'activity'.

I've looked at other questions and tried the following

- Invalidate Caches / Restart
- set "insert imports on paste" to all, checked "optimize imports on the fly" and checked "add unambiguous imports on the fly"

None of those worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.thesgn.app"
android:installLocation="auto">

<!-- versionCode, versionName, minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion properties are set via Gradle script -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="com.thesgn.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.thesgn.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".WebViewAppApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="TheSGN"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.WebViewApp.Orange"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:allowBackup="true">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource" android:resource="@xml/analytics_global_tracker" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode|smallestScreenSize" />

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.thesgn.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_notify" />

</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.activity` would be the name of the package your `MainActivity` is in. You just have to adjust the `android:name` tag accordingly to the hierarchy of your app. If it's on top, that would just be `.MainActivity`, otherwise `.somePackageName.MainActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you closed your Emulator while it loading. simply you can do a **clean build** project and run the **Emulator** again until it's loading your application.

Answer (score 0):

android:name=".activity.MainActivity"

should be

android:name=".MainActivity"